# Rake:test:xx always throw "Don't know how to build task xx" error in Rails 3.2.18, how can I solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I found a article said rails rake support following tasks under namespace:

> rake test:functionals - Run tests for functionalsdb:test:prepare
>
> rake test:integration - Run tests for integrationdb:test:prepare
>
> rake test:plugins - Run tests for pluginsenvironment
>
> rake test:recent - Run tests for recentdb:test:prepare
>
> rake test:uncommitted - Run tests for uncommitteddb:test:prepare
>
> rake test:units - Run tests for unitsdb:test:prepare

But when I try, each of them throws error message like:

> rake aborted!
>   Don't know how to build task 'test:units'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'

When I use --trace, it gives:

> rake aborted!
>   Don't know how to build task 'test:units'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in`invoke_task'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`each'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`run_with_threads'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`block in run'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`run'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rake:23:in`load'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
>   /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'

But it works fine with rake test:

> Loaded suite /Users/ksong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rake
>   Started
>
> Finished in 7.2e-05 seconds.
>
> 0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
>   0% passed
>
> 0.00 tests/s, 0.00 assertions/s

I don't know what's wrong. And when I execute `rake -T`, it doesn't list `rake test`. BTW, my ruby version is 2.0.0.

Comment: Try prefacing your command with `bundle exec`, so `bundle exec rake -T`

Comment: @infused, I tried, the output is the same as just using `rake -T`. The output list does not contain "rake test".